# Не могу выставить по центру див

Tags: html, css

Сижу уже 2 часа не могу блок по центру в диве слайдера поставить. Проблема в том , что я уже все перепробовал.Центрует только когда опредленная ширина типа как щяс 80%. А мне надо чтобы текст что занимает такая была ширина.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сайт кто хочет в  панеле разработчика повыстраивать http://afisha.net.ru/
Вот код:

```
<div class="relative zoom-blurb"><div class="absolute white z1 top-0 bottom-0 right-0 left-0 mx-auto" style="width:80%;height: 40%; margin:auto; ">
                                                                <p class="h1 mb1"><?php echo $data['title'] ?></p>
                                                        <p class=" mt0 mb0 xs-hide">Категория: <?php echo $data['category'] ?> Опубликовано <?php echo showDate($data['datetime']) ?></p>
                                                        <p class="h3 mt1 xs-hide"><?php echo $data['slogan'] ?></p>
                                                            </div><a href="fullpost/<?php echo $data['id'] ?> "><img src="<?php echo $data['image']; ?>" alt=""></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Правильно понял что ты добивалась этого эффекта?
только на этом слайде или вообще на всех?

[image]

Comment: да этого эффекта. ну чтобы для каждого выравнивание стояло? Как вы это сделали?

Comment: добавил фото с изменениями в панели разработчика

Comment: с другими слайдами не смотрел как отображается

Comment: А мне одного достаточно! Спс. И это немного не то что нужно. :) Див занимает 80%, с другими не прокатит. :(

Comment: Посмотрел с другими слайдами и в таком же ключе получается выровнять, но проценты уже другие. Надеюсь помог. Не за что

Comment: Можете попробовать ещё через абсолютное позиционирование дива. может это будет лучше

Comment: Старый код подставил, посмотрел что там было раньше и все заработало. display:table

Comment: посмотрите в сторону flexbox, с их помощью позиционирование элементов по центру блока, становится проще